# Uninstall exe using shortcut from control panel using Wix

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer, shortcut

I am creating MSI installer using Wix for wpf applications.I am creating 2 projects one is Wix set up project and another is a Bootstrapper. There is a file named product.wxs in Setup project and Bundle.wxs in Bootstrapper project.I am creating shortcut in product.wxs file as shown in below code.  I have reference of set up project in Bootstrapper.  I can see this short cut in start menu. When I run this shortcut, it removes application from c:\ where it was installed previously.But it still shows the entry in Control panel(Add or Remove programs).This case happens when I use Exe created by Bootstrapper project.But When I use installer created by Set Up project, it works well.The entry from control panel is also gets removed. I am not able to figure out what is happening with bootstrapper project. 
This is my code for Product.wxs from SetUp project:

```
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuSubfolder" Name="Vizitech Solutions">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcuts" Guid="*">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationShortcut1" Name="Consenus Sweeper" 
                  Description="Consensus"
                  Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]ConsenusSweeper.exe" 
                  WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER">
          <Icon Id="MyAppShortCutIcon" SourceFile="Consensus_128.ico"/>
        </Shortcut>

        <Shortcut Id="UninstallProductStartMenu"
               Name="Uninstall Consensus Sweeper"
              Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe"
              Arguments="/x [ProductCode]"
              Description="Uninstalls Consensus Sweeper"

              >
          <Icon  Id="MyAppUninstallShortCutIcon" SourceFile="Consensus_128.ico"/>

        </Shortcut>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Vizitech\ConsensusSweeper"
                  Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />

        <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuSubfolder" On="uninstall"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="INSTALLFOLDER" On="uninstall"/>
      </Component>
     </Directory>
  </Directory>
```

Following is code for Bundle.wxs from Bootstrapper project:

```
    <Bundle Name="Consensus Sweeper" Version="1.0.0.2" 
            UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE" 
            IconSourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)Libs\Resources\Consensus_128.ico">
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" >
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="License.rtf"  
        LogoFile="FTB.bmp" LogoSideFile="FTB.bmp" />

</BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx45Web"/>
  <MsiPackage Id="MyApplication" SourceFile="$(var.ConsensusSweeper.TargetPath)"
              Visible="no">
    <MsiProperty Name="ALLUSERS" Value="1"></MsiProperty>

  </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bootstrapper was creating 2 entries in control panel.But I was showing only entry of Bootstrapper project and I was hiding MSI installer exe like

```
<MsiPackage Id="MyApplication" SourceFile="$(var.ConsensusSweeper.TargetPath)"
          Visible="no">
```

So whenever I tried to uninstall it from shortcut, the shortcut was actually uninstalling installer which was not visible in control panel.i.e.it was uninstalling installer created using SetUp project with product.wxs.
 Now I just changed the visibility of 2 entries. This time I am Keeping  MSI installer visible and Bootstrapper entry is hidden.
The following is little change in code:

```
 <Bundle DisableModify="yes" DisableRemove="yes">
```

Above code from Bundle.wxs will disables the entry of Bootstrapper in Control panel.
One more change I made in Chain element by keeping Msipackage visible.
The following is change:

```
      <MsiPackage Id="MyApplication" SourceFile="$(var.ConsensusSweeper.TargetPath)" Visible="yes" >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="*">
    <CreateFolder/>
    <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" 
              Name="Consenus Sweeper" Description="Consensus"/>

    <Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct"
              Name="Uninstall My Application"
              Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe"
              Arguments="/x [ProductCode]"
              Description="Uninstalls Consensus Sweeper"/>
    <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuSubfolder" On="uninstall"/>
</Component>
```

Also add to your *Feature* element:

```
<ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />
```

Comment: what version of WiX are you using?

Comment: I am using Wix Toolset v3.8

Comment: I'm also using 3.8, for me its uninstalling from control panel too... Try manually deletem then try again...

Comment: Can you share your code if your code is different from me for uninstall shortcut?

Comment: 1 more question, do you set _ID_ of _Product_ element manually? cause `[ProductCode]` is that ID @edit i mean if you have `Id="*"` or `Id="Your_guid"`? My code is same, i even dont know if im looking right, cause you say uninstall is working, but only it stay in control panel...

Comment: I am setting product Id by generating guid like  Id="E8B361EF-5BA4-4B1F-9883-AEB99C487CE0"

Comment: Ok last thing, if it won't work... i don't know, add to your  _Component Id="ApplicationShortcuts"_ element: `<CreateFolder/>` @Edit i just took your code, and it works fine (well it just don't delete _INSTALLDIR_ but its cause i didnt delete it from code, Control panel is looking good too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63223/discussion-between-dt-sawant-and-buzka91).

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow up to @DT sawant answer: Unfortunately, your solution would present several problems, one of which is the windows logo rules. By hiding the bundle and making the application installed by the bundle visible in ARP, the bundle becomes stranded. That is, uninstalling the application via your 'shortcut' will remove the application, but the boostrapper is still there (invisible). So, if you try to re-install the application via the bootstrapper, then the maintenance UI shows up, instead of a fresh install as intended. In general, it seems like the convenient use of uninstall shortcut and ARP features, in tandem, is not supported in WIX or recommended best practice. It would be nice to have this though.